# High network usage by update service/s in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, bandwidth

**System Specs:**

- Device: Dell Inspiron 5558 (core i5, 8GB RAM)
- OS: Windows 10 - 1607 - 14393.447
- Network Bandwidth - 1 Mbps

**Problem:** I'm getting high network usage by the following services at regular intervals for long duration.

1. Windows Update
2. Update Orchestrator Service
3. Delivery Optimisation
4. Group Policy Client.

I have checked and rechecked but there's no update available when the network is being hogged by these services. I have also disabled 'Updates from more than one place' in advanced update settings. Why is this happening regularly and how can the usage be reduced or stopped? I'm not able to do any network related activity(even browse a website) when these services are hogging the network(low bandwidth as it is). I'm attaching a few screenshots of my Task manager activity and update settings. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Task Manager]

[image: Update Settings]

Comment: this could also be the push service

Comment: @magicandre1981: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean the push notification service?